# Finding Closest Street View Image That Exists

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to load Google Street View based on lat and lng derived from a map click event. Generally it works well, but in some cases Street View does not exist.

If Street View image does not exist, it needs to find it from the closest point that does exist. Is this even possible?

**[In my example](https://jsfiddle.net/hcvw96ff/)**, try clicking inside the buildings that you see on the map. The Street View image will show underneath `#map_canvas`. If the Street View image does not exist, you'll see a message saying that `Street View is not available for this location`.

Also try clicking on the large yellow building along East Lake Blvd. No Street View image exists. However, if you just click outside on one of its sides, you may get the Street View image.

My JS code responsible for Street View is below:

```
// Initialize Google Street View
function initStreetView(location) {
  var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
  var streetviewLatLng = location;
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: location,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    draggable: false,
    clickToGo: false,
    scrollwheel: false
  };

  streetViewMap = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);

  streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(streetviewLatLng, 50, function(streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
    setCarToCentroidPov(streetViewPanoramaData, status, buildingLatLng);
  });
}

// Set Street View to Look at Map Click Event Lat/Lng
function setCarToCentroidPov(streetViewPanoramaData, status, buildingLatLng) {
  if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    var googleCarPosition = streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng;
    // Set the Panorama Position to the Google Car Position Returned by the Street View Service
    streetViewMap.setPosition(googleCarPosition);
    // Calculate the POV from the Panorama Location to the Building Using Google's Geometry Library
    var panoHeading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(googleCarPosition, buildingLatLng);
    streetViewMap.setPov({
      heading: panoHeading,
      zoom: 1,
      pitch: 0
    });
    streetViewMap.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    alert("Street View is not available for this location.");
  }
}
```

Comment: [You could increase the radius](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hcvw96ff/3/), although from the documentation, 50 m or less for the radius **should** return the closest panorama, but it doesn't seem to do that.  Seems to be a bug in the API or the documentation.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for your example. Am going through it. Seems to work better than mine in most cases.